# Mount my Storage account file service in a Web App

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-files

I need to mount my Storage account file service in a Web App. I tried to do that via scm cmd. But Access is denied. How Can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, but apparently this is being worked on and is in the top 6 list of requested features on the Azure Feedback channel.

See [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/6084609-allow-map-azure-file-share-microsoft-azure-file-s) for the current status